# How to convert sqlite3 database to RSS feed for a static site?

Tags: sqlite, rss, feed

I need to create an RSS feed from a sqlite3 database containing blog posts. The site that will use the feed is on Google App Engine but is a static site currently. To create an RSS feed would it be easier to use a server-side script in Python or to use a Windows software tool (e.g. FeedForAll) to produce the news feed, say, once a week? Or is there a simple way to format the feed in a text editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can manually create your feed with a text editor, but your maintenance effort would skyrocket. (Oh, there is a new blogpost, let's edit the feed, paste in the blog post, delete an old blog post....)

Using a desktop tool to generate the feed would just automate the manual process (if you have an extremely high server load, this is a valid idea though).

In the end, you have a database from which you wish to serve textfiles to the cloud. This is something that server-side scripts like ASP.NET / PHP, etc. are meant to do and have a rather history of doing.